# R zombie processes

Tags: r, windows, doparallel, zombie-process

Is there a way to safely remove/stop/shut down those R processes? Using doParallel package
I'm always calling stopImplicitCluster() but apparantly it doesn't affect.
Thanks in advance!
[image]